# How should something like SO's vote count be stored in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm assuming votes on StackOverflow are relations between between users and posts. It would be expensive to count the votes for each page load, so I'm assuming it's cached somewhere. Is there a best practice for storing values that can be computed from other DB data?

1. I could store it in something like Redis, but then it'll be expensive to sort questions by votes.
2. I could store it as a new column in the posts table, but it'll be confusing to other engineers because derived values aren't typically stored with actual data.
3. I could create an entity-attribute-value table just for derived data, so I could join it with the posts table. There's a slight performance hit for the join and I don't like the idea of a table filled with unstructured data, since it would easily end up being filled with unused data.

I'm using MySQL 8, are there other options?

One more consideration is that this data doesn't need to be consistent, it's ok if the vote total is off slightly. So when a vote is created, the vote total doesn't need to be updated immediately, a job can run periodically to update the vote.

Answer (score 1):

"Best practice" is very much situational, and often based on opinion. Here's how I look at it.

Your question seems to be about how to make a database-driven application perform at scale, and what trade-offs are acceptable.

I'd start by sticking to the relational, normalized data model for as long as you can. You say "It would be expensive to count the votes for each page load" - probably not *that* expensive, because you'll be joining on foreign keys, and unless you're talking about very large numbers of records and/or requests, that should scale pretty well.

If scalability and performance are challenges, I'd build a test rig, and optimize those queries, subject them to load and performance testing and add hardware capacity before doing anything else.

This is because normalized databases and applications without duplication/caching are easier to maintain, less likely to develop weird bugs, and easier to extend in future.

If you reach the point where that doesn't work anymore, I'd look at caching. There are a range of options here - you mention 3. The challenge is that once you reach the point where the normalized database because a performance bottleneck, there are usually lots of potential queries which become the bottleneck - if you optimize the "how many votes does a post get?" query, you move the problem to the "how many people have viewed this post?" query.

So, at this point I typically try to limit the requests to the database by caching in the application layer. This can take the form of a Redis cache. In descending order of effectiveness, you can:

- Cache entire pages. This reduces the number of database hits dramatically, but is hard to do with a personalized site like SO.
- Cache page fragments, e.g. the SO homepage has a few dozen questions; you could cache each question as a snippet of HTML, and assemble those snippets to render the page. This allows you to create a personalized page, by assembling different fragments for different users.
- Cache query results. This means the application server would need to interpret the query results and convert to HTML; you would do this for caching data you'd use to assemble the page. For SO, for instance, you might cache "Leo Jiang's avatar path is x, and they are following tags {a, b, c}".

The problem with caching, of course, is invalidation and the trade-off between performance and up-to-date information. You can also get lots of weird bugs with caches being out of sync across load balancers.